# How to fix "Bad Request (status code: 400)" when embed isnt oversized

Tags: python, python-3.x, embed, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot (using discord.py) and it presents the users with a "profile" including how many games they have won (the game isnt important), their score, league and how many games they have lost. There is not much included in the embedded field so I am stumped as to why I am getting this error.

This is going to be a bot managing the League in a game (scores, leagues etc.) and I have already tried replacing the strings of "\u200b" with something else (just two hyphens "--") but its not that (it does the same thing and the \u200b should work anyway).

```
    rankid = 5
    leagueid = 4
    logourl = author.avatar_url
    name = 'Duffy'
    score = 100
    wins = 10
    losses = 10

    if rankid == 0:
        rank = ''
    elif rankid == 1:
        rank = ' Skilled'
    elif rankid == 2:
        rank = ' Adept'
    elif rankid == 3:
        rank = ' Expert'
    elif rankid == 4:
        rank == ' Legendary'
    elif rankid == 5:
        rank = ' Godly'

    if leagueid == 1:
        col = 0xa5744e
        league = '- Bronze League -'
    elif leagueid == 2:
        col = 0xa4bdc4
        league = '- Silver League -'
    elif leagueid == 3:
        col = 0xdae68b
        league = '- Gold League -'
    elif leagueid == 4:
        col = 0xdfd5d60
        league = '- QC Member -'


    embed = discord.Embed(title="-----------------", colour=discord.Colour(col), description="Rank:"+rank+" Duck")

    embed.set_thumbnail(url=logourl)
    embed.set_author(name="Profile of: "+name)

    embed.add_field(name=league, value="​\u200b")
    embed.add_field(name="Score", value=str(score))
    embed.add_field(name="Wins", value=str(wins), inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Losses", value=str(losses), inline=True)


    await client.send_message(message.channel,embed=embed)
```

Gives me the desired embedded field (instead does nothing within discord and spits out the error: discord.errors.HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400))

Comment: Where are you getting your `author` for the `logourl = author.avatar_url` from?

Comment: on_message(message):
    author = message.author

Comment: also nevermind, turns out col = 0xdfd5d60 isnt a colour